# Calling another jQuery function if confirm is true

Tags: jquery, forms, confirm

I'm trying to call another jQuery function if confirm is true, here's the code:

```
jQuery("#adminForm_1").submit(function () {

    var empty = false;
    jQuery(":input", "#adminForm_1").each(function () {
        empty = (jQuery(this).val() == "") ? true : empty;
    });
    if (empty) {

        if (confirm('You have not filled out all of the fields, do you wish to continue?')) {

            jQuery("#adminForm_1").validationEngine({
                ajaxSubmit: true,
                ajaxSubmitFile: "/index.php?option=com_database&view=tripdetails&Itemid=12&client=1&task=save",
                ajaxSubmitMessage: "Client Trip Details Saved",
                inlineValidation: false,
                success: false,
                failure: function () {}
            });

        } else {
            return false;
        };

    }

});
```

^^ the above code doesn't work, but you'll see what I'm trying to do..

Comment: What happens when you run it?

Comment: it refreshes the page and doesn't call the .validationEngine scipt.. no errors in FF though..

Comment: as in no javascript errors.. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to prevent the browser's default action on the form, which is to submit it to the server the traditional way. Either `return false` at the end of your submit handler, or put `e.preventDefault()` at the beginning:

```
jQuery("#adminForm_1").submit(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    ...
```

or:

```
jQuery("#adminForm_1").submit(function () {

    var empty = false;
    jQuery(":input", "#adminForm_1").each(function () {
        empty = (jQuery(this).val() == "") ? true : empty;
    });
    if (empty) {
        if (confirm('You have not filled out all of the fields, do you wish to continue?')) {
            ...
            });
        } 
    }
    return false;
});
```

See [`preventDefault`](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/jQuery.Event#event.preventDefault.28.29):

> Prevents the browser from executing
>   the default action. Use the method
>   isDefaultPrevented to know whether
>   this method was ever called (on that
>   event object).

As as side-note `return false` has the same effect as `preventDefault` plus it stops the bubbling of the event to parent elements. jQuery's mechanism for achieving that is in the [stopPropagation](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/jQuery.Event#event.stopPropagation.28.29) method. In other words, `return false` = `e.preventDefault + e.stopPropagation`

Answer (score 1):

You're not stopping the "normal" submit event from propagating - try adding `return false` after the `.validationEnginge()` method (alternatively moving it out of the `if` block):

```
jQuery("#adminForm_1").submit(function () {
    var empty = false;
    jQuery(":input", "#adminForm_1").each(function () {
        empty = (jQuery(this).val() == "") ? true : empty;
    });
    if (empty) {
        if (confirm('You have not filled out all of the fields, do you wish to continue?')) {
            jQuery("#adminForm_1").validationEngine({
                ajaxSubmit: true,
                ajaxSubmitFile: "/index.php?option=com_database&view=tripdetails&Itemid=12&client=1&task=save",
                ajaxSubmitMessage: "Client Trip Details Saved",
                inlineValidation: false,
                success: false,
                failure: function () {}
            });
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```

Or even

```
jQuery("#adminForm_1").submit(function () {
    var empty = false;
    jQuery(":input", "#adminForm_1").each(function () {
        empty = (jQuery(this).val() == "") ? true : empty;
    });
    if (empty) {
        if (confirm( ... )) {
            jQuery("#adminForm_1").validationEngine({ ...  });
        }
    }
    return false;
});
```