# Form submit true when another function true (jquery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

I have form event on submit. i would like submit form when function (first) is true.

```
$("#form_id").submit(function () {
  if ---------------- {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
});
```

and another function:

```
function (first) {
  return true
}
```

Comment: what is your problem..?

Comment: Will http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1469875/calling-another-jquery-function-if-confirm-is-true help

Comment: i dont know how to take value from function(first) to submit function

Comment: yeah right, but these "value" will you take from your server? what's the cenario? provide more info

Comment: `if(true) { $(this).submit(); } else { /*false*/ }` ?

Comment: Is the second `function` nameless on purpose? If it is not, you can `if(someName(value)){` in your `submit()`, after naming your `function` 'someName'.

Comment: I receive true or false with ajax. And if ajax true then i would like submit function

Comment: my ajax function name is first and i try use if( first() ) {
  return true;
} else {
return false;
 
}
 on submit but still i can submit when ajax function is false

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your comments, you could simply use the `success` setting jQuery's `ajax` offers to `submit()`.

For example, you could embody your `submit()` within a function:

```
function sendMyStuff(){
    $("#form_id").submit(function () {
      ///
    });
}
```

Then in your `ajax`'s `success` event, call it:

```
$.ajax({
  ///
  success: sendMyStuff
});
```

However, if you want to do it your way, you could try the exact opposite of what is described above. Enclose your `ajax` in a function that returns `true`, and call it within your `submit()` event.

EDITED:

```
$("#form_id").submit(function (event) {
    if(someFunction()){
        ///
    } else {
        ///
    }
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: Thank you. if im using my way how to create == true?

Comment: It would be easier to simply do `$("#form_id").submit(function () { if(first()){`.